# User.Identity.Name to SQL parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql, select, insert, sqldatasource

I have this code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDataSource4.SelectParameters["zadavatel"].DefaultValue = this.Page.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Markup:

```
<InsertParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="zadavatel" Type="String" />
</InsertParameters>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:fotbalConnectionString %>" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE Diskuze WHERE Id_Diskuze=@Id_Diskuze" 
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Diskuze] WHERE ([Id_Zapasu] = @Id_Zapasu) ORDER BY [Datum_Vytvoreni] ASC" 
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Diskuze (Autor, TextD, Ip_Adresa, Id_Zapasu) VALUES (@zadavatel, @TextD, '127.0.0.1', @Id_zapasu)">
```

I want insert parameter `zadavatel` to Autor...but I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Odkaz na objekt není nastaven na instanci objektu.
>     (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

I donť know where is the problem :/

Comment: But if you want to **insert** - why are you setting a parameter value on `SelectParameters` ?? Shouldn't you be setting the `InsertParameters` instead?

Comment: Sorry, a bad copy...i edited it...its same error

Comment: i searchet it!! it must be SqlDataSource4.InsertParameters["zadavatel"].Def

Comment: Are you sure that using SqlDataSource is a good thing? Even more, 4 SqlDataSources? It's a bad design and I pray that MS will some day change their minds and destroy such possibility forever. Of course you have problems that are somewhat hard to debug. Connection string  and SQL commands right in the UI :((

Answer (score 1):

You should use `InsertParameters["@zadavatel"]` instead of `SelectParameters["zadavatel"]`.